# Writing to an output file in C

Tags: c, input, fwrite

I am writing a program in C that takes a a command line argument that represents the name of an output file. I then opened the file to write to it. The problem is that when I write something in the command line, it never shows up in the file I was writing to and any text in the file is erased. Here is the code I have for writing to the file from stdin. 
(`fdOut` is the `FILE * stream` that was specified)

```
 while(fread(buf, 1, 1024, stdin))
 {
   fwrite(buf, 1, 1024, fdOut);
 }
```

Comment: There is a good chance that the error is elsewhere. Can you show us more code ? For example, did you open ``fdOut`` properly ?

Comment: Note that `stdin` is not "the command line".  The command line is only what you use to start the program.  I'm assuming you're trying to write something like `cat` that reads from `stdin` but writes to a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code.

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main()
{
        char buf[1024];
        FILE *fdOut;
        if((fdOut = fopen("out.txt","w")) ==NULL)
        {       printf("fopen error!\n");return -1;}
        while (fgets(buf, 1024, stdin) != NULL)
        {
            //   int i ;
            //   for(i = 0;buf[i]!=NULL; ++i)
            //          fputc(buf[i],fdOut);
                 fputs(buf,fdOut);
            //   printf("write error\n");
        }
        fclose(fdOut);
        return 0;
}
```

Note : use Ctrl+'D' to stop input.

Comment: That worked! The only problem is that the error checking for fopen doesn't seem to be working right. If I use a nonexistent file, it will create the file and then write to it.

Comment: Why not `fputs(buf, fdOut)`?  Note that this will copy text OK; it will not copy files that contain zero bytes (such as UTF-16 files) accurately.

Comment: Also, good point about using Control-D to end the input.  Using Control-C (interrupt) would leave the file empty unless you'd typed multiple lines of input.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I use the fputs() function the first time,but it write a extra '\n' after each input.I don't know why...

Comment: No: [`puts()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/puts.html) outputs a newline after the data; [`fputs()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fputs.html) does not.

Comment: @katherine When we open the file with flag "w",it will create the file if it does not exist .So the error checking is excess ,but it's not a error.

Answer (score 0):

let's assume that there is data coming in at `stdin`, d.g. you are using your program like:

```
 cat infile.txt | ./myprog /tmp/outfile.txt
```

then data written with `fwrite()` will be buffered, so it won't appear *immediately* in the output file, but only when your OS decides that it's time to flush the buffer.
you can manually force writing to disk by using

```
 fflush(fdOut);
```

(probably you don't want to do this all the time, as buffering allows for great speedups, esp when writing to slow media)

Comment: Note that it's not your OS that decides when to flush the buffer. It's `libc` who is buffering output data, and it is usually *line-buffered* which means that when a newline is written, it actually calls `write` to flush the buffers.

Answer (score 0):

```
size_t nbytes;
while ((nbytes = fread(buf, 1, 1024, stdin)) > 0)
{
    if (fwrite(buf, 1, nbytes, fdOut) != nbytes)
        ...handle short write...out of space?...
}
```

As you wrote it, you mishandle a short read, writing garbage that was not read to the output.